# Meaning of this differentiation operators

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, mathematical-physics

I have been just reading this paper here: [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/nucl-th/0108073v1.pdf) and was wondering how they carry out the differentiation in (4.9). In principle, this should be just the differentiation of 4.8 with the help of 4.7a. But I don't get what this actually means and how this operator $T$ acts on 4.8? Is here anybody who can provide me with some details?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: I took a stab at it, but, I must also be missing something as I am awash in a power series of $\ln(r)$ which arise from $\frac{\partial}{\partial l}r^l = \ln(r)r^l$.

Comment: My advice, post the question with details and hope someone is fished in...